# Android Java Google Maps, need to check if map is loaded fully before executing dialog

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dialog

I'm trying to figure out if the map is loaded before I open a dialog on the MainActivity (with map fragment) it would be helpful if there was a

```
if(map.isLoaded()){
    //show dialog
}
```

if I just normally open a dialog after the map is already loaded, then it opens fine, but I'm switching activities and I wanted the dialog to open as soon as the activity starts but it seems as if the dialog is beating the loading map, then through the process of it loading, the dialog goes away and the map comes up. I've seen things about javascript and theres something regarding tilesLoaded() but I'm not seeing anything like that either. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html)?

Comment: thanks! didn't even see that! worked exactly as planned

Comment: @jp093121 It was only recently added to the API. Best to check release notes once in a while: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases

Answer (score 4):

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        public void onMapLoaded() {
           //do stuff here
        }
    });
```